# LINQ query IN for array

Tags: linq

I have the following model:

```
public class Device
{
    //....
    private ICollection<TagDevice> _tagDevices;
    public virtual ICollection<TagDevice> TagDevices { get => _tagDevices ?? (_tagDevices = new List<TagDevice>()); protected set => _tagDevices = value; }
}

public class TagDevice
{
    //....
    public int TagId { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select all Devices, which has ALL TagIds from int array.

For example:

```
device1 has tags [1, 2, 3]
device2 has tags [2, 3, 4]
device3 has tags [3, 4, 5]

tagsApplied is [2,3]

result: returned device1 and device2
```

I try

```
        query = query.Where(p => tagsApplied.Contains( )
```

but this method allows only one element, not element list

How to do it?

Comment: what is query? Where  is the list of tags stored?

Comment: I showed model.

Comment: Use the LINQ `All` operator.

Comment: Are you using EF / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x or LINQ to SQL or Objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i suppose the `query` is list of `Device`, change the `contains` function by Excepting `List a` from `List b`, like the following code :

```
IEnumerable<string> result = query
    .Where(device => !tagApplied.Except(device.TagDevices.Select(t=>t.TagId)).Any())
    .Select(x => x.Name);
```

Doc of [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8)

i hope that will help you fix the issue

Comment: Rather than a double negative (`!`...`Except`) why not use `All`? `tagsApplied.All(ta => device.TagDevices.Select(t=>t.TagId).Contains(ta))`

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), you can create an extension method that creates an or expression testing against each member of an array:

```
public static class LinqKitExt { // using LINQKit
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAllIsContained<T,TKey>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T,IEnumerable<TKey>>> keyFne, IEnumerable<TKey> searchTerms) {
        Expression<Func<T,bool>> pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var s in searchTerms)
            pred = pred.And(a => keyFne.Invoke(a).Contains(s));

        return dbq.Where(pred.Expand());
    }
}
```

With this extension available, you can do

```
query = query.WhereAllIsContained(d => d.TagDevices.Select(td => td.TagId), tagsApplied);
```

I believe this should translate to SQL, but I don't have an EF Core model with a collection property to test.